# how to add image view to end of ArrayAdapter<>

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add some button/image view to the end of my  ArrayAdapter. 
But the problem when I add my button then see it on every item, and not on the end of my list.
I tried to add  this on xml

```
android:id="@+id/AddRss"
```

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconremove"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconfav"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rss" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AddRss"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="addRss"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/rss" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this layout represent cell item of a list view? If you want to add a button at the end of a list view you can use ListView#addFooterView(). NOTE: Call this before calling setAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a footer view layout consisting of text that you want to set as footer and then try

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Layout for footer could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/footer_text_1" 
        android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14dip" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

hope this will help.

Comment: did like that   adapter = new GeneralRssAdapter(this,R.layout.titlesrss, data);
  View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
  lv.addFooterView(footerView);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);                 but still cant see the text just my list